# Fix text field position when air window resize

Tags: actionscript-3, air

How to fix a text field width and height as well as its position when air window re-size  in flash action script  with air?
 I am trying to use text field like as notepad editor area but when when i re-size adobe air window  the text field property automatically adjust ,mean it change its position .
 i want that   when the width of air window  re-size, text field should adjust its width according to adobe air window width .when the height of air  re-size the  text field should adjust it's height according to Adobe Air window height  and text field position(x,y) should fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For controlling resize of components, in the beginning of application configure stage:

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

Subscribe for resizing of the stage, and implement resize of TextField:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onResize);

function onResize(e:Event):void {
    //Implement logic, screen size is (stage.stageWidth x stage.stageHeight)
    const padding: int = 20;
    myTextField.width = stage.stageWidth - 2*padding;
    myTextField.height = stage.stageHeight - 2*padding;
}
```

Comment: thanks Nicolas Silver its  working exact what i wanted.